# How to reload images array using nostra13's UniversalImageLoader?

Tags: java, android

I'm using the nostra13 UniversalImageLoader to load a bunch of images into a gridview and its working beautifully, but when a user clicks an item on my menu, i need the images to change (not open a new page, but reload/refresh the images on the same page)

I'm calling the imageloader like so:

```
protected ImageLoader imageLoader;

imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);

options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
    .cacheInMemory()
    .cacheOnDisc()
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .build();

final GridView main_gridview = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.main_gridview);
main_gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imageUrls.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = (ImageView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, options);

            return imageView;
        }
    }
```

So as you can see the Extras.IMAGES is the string array containing the various URLs, so when a user clicks said button on the menu, I have the array containing the new URLS, but am not sure how to 'refresh' the image adapter?

I understand you can 'add' pictures to the gridview on the fly, but I didnt see in nostra's documentation if you could completely refresh the whole array..

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

PS. Sorry if the answer to this is obvious I'm only about a week into android dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. Just set ImageUrls to my string array of updated images, then I declared the ImageAdapter object at the top and called notifyDataSetChanged() on that object like so:

```
ImageAdapter imgAdapter;

main_gridview.setAdapter(imgAdapter);

imgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```